# delete from mysql by join in second table

Tags: mysql

We have 2 tables below :

Table1

```
Name    roll     priority    count(*) 
def     12       8           58
def     11       7           54
def     10       7           172
abc     12       7           2
abc     13       6           307
abc     11       6           3472
xyz     12       7           132
xyz     11       9           2345
xyz     12       9           1234
```

Table2

```
name    roll    priority    
abc     12      10  
xyz     12      8
```

> [Source data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQn5p.png)

And in above I need to delete all entry of priority >5 but delete the entry with match from Table2.

Means the entry in Table1 shouldn't be delete for priority 10 with name abc and roll 12 if same is in Table1.

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts, then only we can help you.

Comment: There isn't an abc priority 10 or an xyz priority 8 in table 1 so all should be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep in `table1` the entries that exists in `table2`, you can perform a left outer join.

Thoses entries can be `SELECT`ed like this :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.Name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
    AND t1.priority > 5;
```

And now, applying this join to a delete statement is quite the same :

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
    AND t1.priority > 5;
```

[Try it yourself](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dczsriXA3hpzfAMBoMUYac/0)